# Understanding Blazor hosting

Tags: .net-core, client-side, blazor

**Disclaimer**
I am referring to `Blazor` hosted , not `server-side` !

Can someone please explain me when running `browser`-hosted `Blazor` , why do i need to place in the `Server.Startup` the extension `app.UseBlazor<Client.Startup>` ? 
If the `Blazor` client is already hosted in  a `net core project` -> `Client.Startup` why does my `Server` project need to add this extension ?

Isn't the `client` supposed to be decoupled from the server?

I am missing something here ? Why does my `Server` project need to know about the `Client`  since my `Client` project is already standalone ?

[image]
I have added a picture.
So as you can see in my picture , if the server is communicating via `http` with the client, why do i need to add the extension ?
Blazor is already running in a `asp-net-core` which is the `Client` project am i not right?

Comment: I'm not positive if you are referring to "standalone" blazor or "asp.net core hosted".  If the latter, the whole point of what you are referring to is to allow the server to host the client-side blazor content.

Comment: To elaborate -- you have a nice client-side hosted blazor app.  That's great and all, but how does that client side content get delivered to your user?  That requires a server.  Hence, "asp.net core hosted".  If you want to host a pure client-side version yourself, you can deploy it to S3 or whatever.  But a lot of folks want the entire transaction to be under one solution -- hence the latter model.

Comment: But the `client` is already hosted in a `asp-net-core`project am i not right? The `Client.Startup` is the `Startup` of the server that hosts `Blazor`.

Comment: No...the `Client.Startup` is what runs within the hosted process.  But you still need something to actually host it, no?

Comment: Oh, so basically the `Client.Startup` is the `thing` that makes the your `.NET` code compile to `wasm` and not the `server` that hosts your resulted `wasm` code.I see now.And when you use `app.UseBlazor<something>` in your `server` project you basically say "this guy hosts the wasm".

Comment: .NET code is not compiled to wasm. Only the runtime; that is mono. No, it says "Daniel Roth hosts the wasm" ;]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`Why does my Server project need to know about the Client since my Client project is already standalone ?`"

No, yours is not a standalone project. Your project contains two apps. Just read what you wrote yourself. Do try to remove your server project and run the Blazor app. You've got a front-end app (Blazor) running in the Browser. But you need an app to serve the Blazor app:  ASP.NET Core app that runs on a server.

"`Blazor is already running in a asp-net-core which is the Client project am i not right?`"

As far as I know, Blazor is running under mono webassembly.

I would suggest you to read the contents of the UseBlazor method to learn what it does, and why it is needed. And as far as I recall it's Client.Program rather than Client.Startup.

Comment: By standalone i was referring when you create a `blazor` template.(Just the client project)

Comment: @Adrian, here's a link to an article named Host and deploy Razor Components by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/razor-components/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#client-side-blazor-hosted-deployment-with-aspnet-core

Comment: I'm starting with blazor and curious about the same question of op. If you check the files for the client version is the same of the client of hosted app. Im i missing something? By standalone i think @BercoviciAdrian referenced it right. Client version is to run without the hosted(server).

Comment: Delete the server project from the solution. Delete exe output from .csproj.. it should run as a client blazor app..